# How to get Grails to the cloud

Tags: cloud

Friends, I have developed an application using Grails 2.4.4 on Windows 7 (64-bit) using JDK 1.7 and trying to deploy and test it in the Cloud, but get error, can you help ?

So far, I have created a trial a/c on [Piviotal](https://login.run.pivotal.io/login) Installed CLI as per the [documentation](http://docs.run.pivotal.io/devguide/installcf/install-go-cli.html).
Tried to push the app using the command below,

```
cf push demo
```

**Encountered Error below**

```
OUT     Staging failed: An application could not be detected by any available buildpack
```

Would appreciate any help on how to get around this ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](http://docs.run.pivotal.io/buildpacks/java/gsg-grails.html), I tried

```
cf push demo -p c:\dev\workspace\demo\target\demopayment-app-0.1.war
```